# Fitting Integral to data

Tags: scipy, integral

I am trying to fit data to a function f(x) that is an integral over T. x is the upper boarder of the Integral. I am trying to do it with scipy.curve_fit() but I don't know how to write my integral as a function that can be passed to curve_fit.
I had a look at similar problems but I didn't see anything that fits to my problem.

I cannot provide any guess values for A and Ea since I have no clue at all what they could be as of now.

```
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import integrate

class get_Ton:
 def __init__(self):
  self.data=np.genfromtxt('test3.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=8)
 def loop(self):
    def fit_tangent():
      tck = interpolate.splrep(self.x, self.y, k=2, s=0)
      dev_1 = interpolate.splev(self.x, tck, der=1)

      def integrand(T, A, Ea):
        return A*np.exp(-Ea/(8.314*T))
      def polyn(x, A, Ea):
        return integrate.quad(integrand, 25, x, args=(A, Ea))[0]

      vcurve = np.vectorize(polyn)
      p, e = optimize.curve_fit(vcurve, self.x, self.y, [2000, 150])
      xd = np.linspace(50, 70, 100)

      plt.plot(self.x, self.y, "o")
      plt.plot(xd, vcurve(xd, *p))

    for i in range((list(np.shape(self.data)[1:2]))[0]):
        if i % 2 == 0:
         self.temp=self.data[:,i]
         self.scat=self.data[:,i+1]
         self.x=[26.192, 26.861000000000001, 27.510000000000002, 28.178000000000001, 28.856000000000002, 29.515000000000001, 30.183, 30.823, 31.5, 32.158999999999999, 32.856000000000002, 33.515000000000001, 34.145000000000003, 34.823, 35.491, 36.168999999999997, 36.837000000000003, 37.533999999999999, 38.164000000000001, 38.832000000000001, 39.481000000000002, 40.158999999999999, 40.826999999999998, 41.496000000000002, 42.164000000000001, 42.832000000000001, 43.500999999999998, 44.188000000000002, 44.837000000000003, 45.505000000000003, 46.173000000000002, 46.832000000000001, 47.500999999999998, 48.188000000000002, 48.828000000000003, 49.496000000000002, 50.173999999999999, 50.813000000000002, 51.481000000000002, 52.112000000000002, 52.808999999999997, 53.439, 54.116, 54.765999999999998, 55.453000000000003, 56.101999999999997, 56.761000000000003, 57.429000000000002, 58.078000000000003, 58.737000000000002, 59.442999999999998, 60.082999999999998, 60.770000000000003, 61.448, 62.125999999999998, 62.756, 63.414999999999999, 64.082999999999998, 64.742000000000004, 65.420000000000002, 66.087999999999994, 66.747, 67.415000000000006]
         self.y=[1553.5, 1595.0, 1497.8, 1695.5999999999999, 1328.7, 1279.0, 1547.8, 1412.8, 1037.0, 1473.5, 1447.4000000000001, 1532.5999999999999, 1484.2, 1169.5, 1395.2, 1183.5999999999999, 949.01999999999998, 1238.0999999999999, 1225.5999999999999, 924.80999999999995, 1650.5999999999999, 803.96000000000004, 1245.7, 1190.0, 1207.0, 1294.0, 1174.9000000000001, 1229.8, 1260.0, 1129.2, 1142.9000000000001, 987.63999999999999, 1389.5999999999999, 1366.0, 1102.0999999999999, 1325.5, 1258.9000000000001, 1285.7, 1217.5, 871.47000000000003, 820.24000000000001, 1388.7, 1391.0, 1400.3, 2482.5999999999999, 3360.5999999999999, 7013.5, 11560.0, 16525.0, 22538.0, 32556.0, 43878.0, 59093.0, 67977.0, 75949.0, 82316.0, 90213.0, 90294.0, 99928.0, 128240.0, 181280.0, 226380.0, 223260.0]
         fit_tangent()
         plt.ylim((-100,1000000))
         plt.show()

def main():
    this=get_Ton()
    this.loop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "a function f(x) that is an integral over x" doesn't make sense: the value of the integral doesn't depend on x, but only on the integration boundaries (which you seem to fix at [25,65]). Therefore `polyn` doesn't depend on x, and should only take `A` and `Ea` as parameters, which will then be optimized by `optimize.curve_fit`.

Comment: Thanks for your response: I am referring to the Arrhenius denaturation model: FD=1-exp(-1/B*Int(k(T)dT)) as described in this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4709256/

Comment: I changed the question according to your comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues here. First, the function `polyn` does not depend on the variable of integration T, since this variable is integrated out. Remove T from its list of parameters. Accordingly, drop one of numerical values in trueydata computation:

```
trueydata = vcurve(truexdata, 3, 4)
```

Second, `quad` returns a tuple `(integral_value, integral_error)`. Use `[0]` to return only the integral value.

```
def polyn(x, A, Ea):
    return integrate.quad(integrand, 25, x, args=(A, Ea))[0]
```

Third, provide an initial guess for parameter values to `curve_fit`. If you don't, it will likely report unable to determine the number of parameters to fit. Even if successful, it will blindly use all-ones for the initial guess. An initial guess supplied by a human with an understanding of the optimization problem is often the difference between success and failure of multivariable optimization.

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(vcurve, xdata, ydata, [2, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these very helpful suggestions. I adapted and extended my script accordingly. I now added some real data. 
I cannot provide any guess values for A and Ea since I have no clue at all what they could be as of now. I now receive another error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I think I was able to solve it. I edited the code accordingly.